# Initial state of state monad and how it first gets passed along

Tags: haskell, state, monads

I was reading about the [State monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State) and after writing the code below I cannot understand how the initial state (`mkStdGen 42`) is passed into the `rollDice` function?

How can `get` work on that initial value?

I understand how the `rollDice` function works, but I cannot imagine how the initial state is lifted into the monad.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import System.Random

rollDice :: State StdGen Int
rollDice = do
    generator <- get
    let (x, s) = randomR (1,6) generator
    put s
    return x

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ evalState rollDice (mkStdGen 42)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep things simple, think about a `State s a` as a function, which takes an initial state `s` and returns a value and a new state `(a , s)`, just as in the wikibook:

```
newtype State s a = S { runState :: s -> (s , a) }
```

Now lets use `rollDicePure = runState rollDice`. What's `rollDicePure` type? Given that `runState` only removes the `State` newtype, it should be

```
rollDicePure :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
```

So `runState` (or `evalState`/`execState`) simply turn a stateful computation into a simple function, whose argument is the initial state.

If you wonder how `get` then gets this state, think of it as

```
getPure :: s -> (s, s)
getPure st = (st, st)
```

The actual definitions are a little bit more complicated than that, but the semantics hold.

Comment: I think this part of your answer made everything click into place: "Given that `runState` only removes the `State` newtype". I'm still not accustomed with how the `State` type is actually a function, and that's where the argument comes from.